# translation for "der bringt es mir bei"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

The complete sentence is:

> In unserer Möbelwerkstatt arbeitet ein griechischer Schnitzer, der bringt es mir bei.

What I understood:

> a Greek carpenter works at our furniture workshop, he will bring it.

Help me with the second part of the sentence.

Comment: The verb you are looking for is *beibringen*, not *bringen*.

Comment: @Janka Even _beibringen_ doesn't clearly translate to _teaching_, but from that context it does. But I am _incompetent_, so what :-P ...

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/beibringen has the meaning you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> In unserer Möbelwerkstatt arbeitet ein griechischer Schnitzer, der bringt es mir bei.

The correct translation is

> > A Greek carpenter works at our furniture workshop, he is teaching me.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense in the story I am reading. thanks

Comment: It should be _he teaches_ instead of _he is teachung_.

Comment: Ich kann das leider nur auf Deutsch sagen: Das _es_ in '_der bringt **es** mir bei_' zeigt an, dass vorher die Technik genannt wurde, die dem '_ich_' beigebracht wird. (Vielleicht hieß der Satz davor 'Ich wollte schon immer schnitzen können'.) Das Objekt '_es_' fehlt in der Übersetzung. Wenn es sich z.B. um das Schnitzhandwerk handelt, müsste die Übersetzung lauten: _A Greek carver works at our furniture workshop, he teaches me carving_ - um z.B. klarzustellen, dass es sich nicht um 'Möbelbau' handelt.

Comment: Maybe better "..., he is teaching *it* to me.". Whatever "it" may be.